# Are the path bonuses offered on a per save file or game basis?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

There are various bonus items available as a reward for purchasing additional routes. Are they used up on a per play through/save file basis or per game cartridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I first played through Fates on my friend's DS and was able to collect the rewards each time I started a new route I assume that it would be per save file.